# IndexedDB vs Cookie Security

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, indexeddb

As you know, IndexedDB and Cookie are both used for persistent storage on web browser.

Cookie-related security task has some aspects, which are [Session Fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) or [Session Hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack). Attackers often use the below methods to achieve these.

- [Cross-site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))
- [Cross-site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))
- [Man in the Middle (MitM)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

I've been doing some research about IndexedDB security. However, there are not so many documents about this stuff.

My questions are:

- When I use IndexedDB instead of cookie, will I face the same security tasks? Why?
- How can I make IndexedDB more secure?

Answer (score 1):

> When I use IndexedDB intead of cookie, will I face the same security tasks? Why?

Consider that a cookie is sent to the server with the *request* whereas IndexedDB is only read once a page has loaded.

If you DO find some resources where people more knowledgeable than me have discussed the issues you raise please respond with them here.

Answer (score 1):

One key disadvantage of IndexedDB (and any other client side storage) is that you can set `httpOnly` on a cookie and it'll only be sent in requests (not accessible to JavaScript with `document.cookie`).

With any client accessible storage (including cookies without `httpOnly`) you can be vulnerable to malicious JS on your page (XSS) stealing them (up to you and your threat model whether you're concerned about malicious JS).